# Creating numbered list of output

Tags: python, list, sorting, python-3.x, tuples

How can I edit my code such that my output:

```
the      8512
and      7759
i        6182
to       6027
a        4716
of       4619
he       2873
in       2846
you      2777
was      2457
```

becomes

```
1.    the    8512
2.    and    7759
3.    i      6182
4.    to     6027
5.    a      4716
6.    of     4619
7.    he     2873
8.    in     2846
9.    you    2777
10.   was    2457
```

I attempted to use the enumerate function

```
for rank, (value,num) in enumerate(sorted_list):
```

however this leaves me with the same output. Could I somehow append ranking into the list where value and num is defined?

```
d = dictionary(word_list)


def sort_key (d):
    return d[1]

number = int(sys.argv[1])
sorted_list = sorted(d.items(), key=sort_key, reverse=True)[:number]


for (value,num) in sorted_list:
    value = value.ljust(5)
    num = str(num).rjust(5)

    print("{}\t{}".format(value,num))
```

Comment: Can you show us how you used `enumerate()`? That's **exactly** what you should be using to add a line count.

Comment: @MartijnPieters by stating for rank, (value,num) in enumerate(sorted_list): in place of for (value,num) in sorted_list:

Comment: But then you have the `rank` value you want, albeit off by one. See my answer; I gave `enumerate()` a `start` argument to start counting at 1 instead of 0, but you do need to make sure you *print* that `rank` value. Even without `start` you can still easily add 1 to the produced rank.

Comment: Note that sorting *strings* will result in lexicographical sorting, *not* numerical! For numbers that use the same number of digits that's fine, but not when you have shorter or longer sequences.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd still use `enumerate()`; you didn't show how you used it but it but it solves your issue:

```
for index, (value,num) in enumerate(sorted_list, start=1):
    print("{}.\t{:<5}\t{:>5}".format(index, value,num))
```

I folded your `str.ljust()` and `str.rjust()` calls into the `str.format()` template; this has the added advantage that it'll work for any value you can format, not just strings.

Demo:

```
>>> word_list = '''\
... the      8512
... and      7759
... i        6182
... to       6027
... a        4716
... of       4619
... he       2873
... in       2846
... you      2777
... was      2457
... '''.splitlines()
>>> d = dict(line.split() for line in word_list)
>>> sorted_list = sorted(d.items(), key=lambda i: i[1], reverse=True)
>>> for index, (value,num) in enumerate(sorted_list, start=1):
...     print("{}.\t{:<5}\t{:>5}".format(index, value,num))
... 
1.  the      8512
2.  and      7759
3.  i        6182
4.  to       6027
5.  a        4716
6.  of       4619
7.  he       2873
8.  in       2846
9.  you      2777
10. was      2457
```

Comment: If I wanted to have the minimum amount of spacing between the three sections would I have to keep ljust() & rjust()?

Comment: @Silverfin: no, `str.ljust()` and `str.rjust()` can be entirely handled with the [format specification mini language](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language) functionality.

Comment: Peters the \t tab seemed to prevent me from altering the distance between the sections, I went ahead and used just() methods however im having trouble getting the '.' to line up correctly. - see edit.

Comment: @Silverfin: then why are you using a tab at all then?

Comment: @Silverfin: you can use `'{}.'.format(index)` to format *just* the number, than  put that into the larger per-line format with a field width and alignment. `print("{:<3}\t{:<5}\t{:>5}".format('{}.'.format(index), value,num))`, for example.