# Python:embedded for loops: numbering list output

Tags: python, list, for-loop, embedding

Thank you for clicking. Trying to print a numbered list. Have a for loop for printing list. Ie.

```
print("COMPOUND:EMBED=okay but not right")
# for num in range(1,6+1):
#   for error in errors_list:
#       num=str(num)
#       print(num + ".", error, end=", ")
# print()
```

My wanted output is say:

1. list_item_1
2. list_item_2
3. three,..

Given an exact number of 6 elements, the output is instead:

```
1. list_item_1
1. list_item_2
1. three,..
2. list_item_1
2. list_item_2
2. three,..
3. list_item_1,..list_item_1
```

Individually, the print is okay. Ie. `for item` and `for range`. I've tried embedding the opposite way, list[i] and compounding the two for statements with and. The last of which retrieves: "num is not defined"?

Comment: the primary answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/522563/accessing-the-index-in-python-for-loops has a good workaround. Thank you for the linking. I had forgotten about the count specifics available with while.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use enumerate function:

```
for index, error in enumerate(errors_list):
    print(index + ".", error, end=", ")
```

Comment: Is it possible to do it with only for loops?

Comment: What makes you think that is not a `for` loop?

Comment: Haven't learned enumerate yet. Just range(). Is it possible to do it with only those two? Saw enumerate as solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29074749/creating-numbered-list-of-output

Comment: yes, you could use it like written above, also you could add parameter start=1 to start enumerate from 1.